# What's the word for "angry boredom"?

Tags: synonyms

I just saw that "Cinderella" is being released again as a live action film, and it's directed by Kenneth Branagh. This makes me so bored, but in an enraged way. Is there a word for this?

Comment: What do you mean, it "makes you so bored"? How can a simple fact, expressed as a brief sentence, induce boredom? (And what's "an enraged way" of being bored? Are you sure you understand what the words "bored" and "boredom" mean?)

Comment: I dunno, sounds to me like a fit of [pique](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pique) on your part. Do you stamp your foot when this happens?

Comment: _Sullenness_ is a possibility.

Comment: I initially thought *exasperate*, but no dictionary gives this a definition as boredom or similar. Though I would use it when I was tired of a continual annoyance.

Comment: That doesn't sound like boredom to me. Antipathy, rather than apathy.

Comment: @keshlam This is close to what I'm describing! Thanks.

Comment: Or you might call it "aggressive-nonpassive ennui."

Answer (score 1):

I couldn’t think of a word combining “anger” and “boredom” but the frustration you feel could perhaps be described as states of "vexation" or "annoyance".

> **VEXATION** *noun*
>   1: the act of harassing or vexing:  troubling 
>   2: the quality or state of being vexed:  irritation 
>   3: a cause of trouble:  affliction; see Merriam-Webster [vexation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vexation)
>   **ANNOYANCE** *noun*
>   1: the act of annoying or of being annoyed 
>   2: the state or feeling of being annoyed:  vexation 
>   3: a source of vexation or irritation:  nuisance  see Merriam-Webster [annoyance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annoyance)

Answer (score -1):

I would say "discontent".  But also "apathy" or "ennui".  I think you may have to concatenate more than one word to express the feeling you are looking for adequately.